# URLLoader stuck at Open event for long time

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My app loads an external URL (XML file) every 30 seconds. The app is set in startup so it starts whenever the system starts. The URLLoader stucks on the "open" event after every reboot of system. If I close the app and relaunch it, it works perfectly fine. I have added all event listeners on this URLLoader to see where is the problem. Every time it stuck at URLLoader open event. This is the straight forward code, does not seem to be any complexity. I have also tried exporting it with "Access network only" in publish settings.

```
private var liveFeedLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
private var feedUpdateTimer:Timer = new Timer(30000);

private function init(e:Event):void {
    liveFeedLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, liveFeedLoaderErrFx);
    liveFeedLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, liveFeedLoaderFx);
    feedUpdateTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, checkForUpdate);

    liveFeedLoader.load(new URLRequest("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/abcd/XYZ.xml"));
    feedUpdateTimer.start();
}
```

Comment: Did you got some errors (IO error, security, ...) ? Try also to listen to [`httpStatus`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#event:httpStatus) and [`httpResponseStatus`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#event:httpResponseStatus) (AIR) events may be your app didn't get connection to your server for any reason (internet connection is not yet available at the startup of the OS, firewall, ...) ...

Comment: Yes I have added IO, Security and httpStatus all events. But it not move forward after "open" event. At the same time when its stuck at open, if I try to open that URL in browser, it loads in browser. So I think its not firewall issue.

Comment: What I meant is to use those events to see if there are some problems ... What did you got as HTTP status for example ?

Comment: HTTP status event is not executed. It stucks before that, I just get Open event after I call URLLoader.load(); Not even the progress event is executed.

Comment: It's weird ! I think it's a problem of connection, to be sure, try to test another online URL, then a local one, then use a timeout inside your app to start the first connection after for example 2 or 3 minutes ... also is this a Flash Player app or an AIR one ?

Comment: Ok, I'll try loading some other URL first. Its Flash Player app.

Comment: I have tried loading a different URL and load that old URL in the new URL's load-complete. First URL loads successfully but still same for old URL. But seems like issue is solved if I am using "http://.." instead of "https://...". Seems like some restriction on the device which it not enabling the https access when system starts. Testing on it more.